# SQLAlchemy insert returning primary key with multiple values

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy's insert and execute methods with a list of dictionaries as the values, and to get back the inserted ids. The database is Postgres, which should support RETURNING.

The code looks more or less like this:

```
table = MyThing.__table__
insert_stmt = table.insert().values({"name": bindparam("name_val")}).returning(table.c.id)
values = [{"name_val": "a"}, {"name_val": "b"}]
result = session.execute(insert_stmt, values).fetchall()
```

(trimmed down for readability and some obfuscation)

When the value list is bigger than one (as in the example above) I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) no results to fetch

but when the list only have one value the new id is returned properly.

I understand that I probably missed something in the way I'm using returning but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same bind parameter is repeated in the list of values you're passing in the second argument to `session.execute`.

`values` ought to be a list when inserting multiple values and sqlalchemy by default binds the parameters unless `literal_binds` option is set to `True` so that it is safe to do without explicitly binding the parameters

```py
values = [{"name_val": "a"}, {"name_val": "b"}]
insert_stmt = table.insert().values(values).returning(table.c.id)
result = session.execute(insert_stmt).fetchall()
```

Say you wanted to keep the existing explicit binding,  `values` passed for the insert statement must be a keyword argument. Your existing query will be updated as follow:

```py
bind_params = [{"name_val": "a"}, {"name_val": "b"}]
insert_stmt = table.insert().values(name_val=bindparam("name_val")).returning(table.c.id)
result = session.execute(insert_stmt, bind_params).fetchall()
```

Comment: The underlying reason is that when passing bindparams 
to `values()` and a list of argument collections (bigger than 1) to `execute()` SQLA uses [`executemany()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany), use of which on operations returning result sets is undefined, so anything could happen.

Comment: Here's where the use of `executemany()` is explained: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements

Comment: The first suggestion renders a single `INSERT ... VALUES` statement and simple `execute()` instead of using `executemany()`, and so can return results.

Comment: That's an interesting explanation @IljaEverilä. I'm surprised that `executemany` is invoked on the connection given the case that the compiled statement is a single one. Thanks for mentioning this.